# bytecode instrumentation to native java functions

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am using asm to do byte code instrumentation into java function.
Is there a way to do the same for jre native functions? Maybe a way to wrap the native function with a java function?

My purpose at the end is to get a list of all functions that ran with their arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `native` methods are declared in the class file, you can replace them just like any other method. The tricky part is how to invoke the original method. To achieve this you can create another `native` method which will be linked to the original `native` code.

This must happen at loading time as most JVMs do not support adding methods afterwards. There is a feature to help linking your new helper method to the original code, the *native method prefix*. The [documentation of `Instrumentation.setNativeMethodPrefix`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#setNativeMethodPrefix%28java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer,%20java.lang.String%29) explains the details.

Comment: I came over this problem, since I wanted to wrap some sun.misc.Unsafe native methods. The class is loaded rather early, so it cannot be initially defined with the wrapped natives. I brought this up here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/serviceability-dev/2015-June/017495.html - maybe somebody will have an idea.

Comment: @eckes: Instrumentation works for JNI methods only. Some JRE `native` methods are just intrinsics, i.e. the JVM knows these methods and replaces their invocations with an internal operation when encountered. So for such methods, instrumenting the method itself doesn’t work but you can use your transformer to replace the *invocations* with other code rather than modifying the method.

Comment: Agreed, instrumentation does work for JNI methods (by wrapping them with a prefixed version). That is however not possible on already loaded classes (since they do not allow to add methods when redefining them). At least I dont know how. And yes it might not work for intrinsics, but in my case `Unsafe.allocateMemory()` is not an intrinsic.